# In my rails app using Devise, when an unsigned in user visits root they are redirected to /users/sign_in instead of the root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my rails app using Devise, when an unsigned in user visits root they are redirected to /users/sign_in instead of the root path; root path works fine with signed in users.  The same thing happens when I click the navbar logo which is a link with the home_path which is root, I am redirected to /users/sign_in just like when visiting root.  Here are my routes:

```
  get 'home' => 'static_pages#home', as: "home"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  root 'static_pages#home'
```

The link that takes me to /users/sign_in instead of home_path/root_path in navbar template:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= home_path %>">Brand</a>
```

I am using angular on the front end so this is what the path looks like when a signed in user visits root:

```
http://localhost:3000/home#/
```

If if I manually change the url to /home#/ or /home I am still redirected to users/sign_in.

I can't think of any other information to include.  Is this just default behavior by Devise that I need to override? Can't seem to find anything on automatic redirecting in the docs.  Thanks for the help.

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    home_path
  end
end
```

static_pages controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you include your ApplicationController and/or StaticPagesController?

Comment: Yes I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ApplicationController, which StaticPagesController subclasses, you set `before_action :authenticate_user!`, which will be triggered for all actions, which attempts to authenticate a User.

This means, that when a User isn't signed in, the authentication check will fail, and you will be redirected to the User sign in route.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the helper `authenticate_user!` only allows signed in users to access the web pages. You need to add `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` to the `statics_controller` in order to let the *non-loggedin* users to access the `home` page

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def home
  end
end
```